# Generating nodes where edges meet, PostGIS, pgRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

Recently I was doing some research on how to assign nodes (as POINT type geometry) to existing edges of a topology network and store them in a different table. Call it nodes table.

I have all the edges, they have source and target fields among some other fields as well.
My main idea is, that say, I want to input a location  - POINT(lat, lng) - into my routing app. Then what I want my app to do is to find the point closest to my given location in the nodes table in order to start the routing process.

In my research, I examined the functions `ST_StartPoint()` and `ST_EndPoint()` as possible functions that could come handy while implementing this. Ideally, I would loop thru the edges and get and record both the start- and the endpoints of each, but that raises another issue of having multiple identical points in the nodes table.

Am I on the right track of implementing this right or could you advise a better solution?
Any feedbacks or ideas are welcome!

Thanks in advance

Tamas

p.s.: The proximity search feature is fine, I can do that. The only issue is the node generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All information you need is already in your road network table if it contains `source`, `target` and `geometry` information. With this information you can for example create a `VIEW` that contains all nodes with point geometry:

```
CREATE VIEW nodes_from_ways AS 
    SELECT source AS node, ST_StartPoint(the_geom) FROM ways 
  UNION 
    SELECT target AS node, ST_EndPoint(the_geom) FROM ways;
```

With `UNION` you combine `source` and `target` and only unique node ID's should remain.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help dkastl. I pretty much figured out the solution from underdark's blog entry: http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/ and your answer was helpful too. Thanks =)